# String Occurence Frequency in a text file (Python)

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am struggling to find a way to get a count of several words in a log file.

```
f = open("log.txt")
total = 0

fruits = raw_input("Enter word separated by a comma: ").split(",")

for fruit in fruits:
    for line in f:
        if fruit in line:
            total += 1      
    print fruit + ":" + str(total)
    total = 0

f.close()
```

I'm seeking output such as "Banana:5 Apple:3". But the output from the code above gives every word after the first word a count of 0.

Output:

```
Banana:5
Apple:0
Strawberry:0
```

Comment: What does `log.txt` look like?

Comment: you have to bring the file cursor back to the beginning of the file, put `f.seek(0)` at the bottom of your `for fruit` loop. or just use the code in the possible duplicate, way easier

Comment: I'm almost sure the @RNar's assertion is the right answer.

Comment: @RNar Thank you! Adding the f.seek(0) at the bottom of the for fruit loop resolved the issue. I'll research on it to get a better understanding of how it's used and why it worked. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @glenn126a no problem, however, even if it works, that doesnt mean that's the best way to do it. With this method, you are reading the file for every word which means that it will not grow very well for large files or large number of words. I suggest looking into the answers that people have posted such as switch the order of your for loops or using Counter (personally, I would use Counter because it's so easy)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Counter for this. Read more about Counter [in Python docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
print Counter("abracadabra")

>> Counter({'a': 5, 'r': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1})
```

In your use case, an unoptimized version could be like so,

```
from collections import Counter

with open(file_path, "r") as fh:
    data = Counter(" ".join(fh.readlines()).split(" "))

fruits = raw_input("Enter word separated by a comma: ").split(",")
for fruit in fruits:
    print("{0}: {1}".format(fruit, data[fruit]))
```

What you are passing to counter above is a list of all the words from your file. Counter will then take care of counting them.
If it matters to your use case, you will have to consider cases and convert all the data from file into lower or upper before passing that to Counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of the `for` loops in order to avoid going back to the start of the file. Then for each line save the number of occurrences of each word in `dict` something like this:

```
f = open("log.txt")
total = {}

fruits = raw_input("Enter word separated by a comma: ").split(",")

for line in f:
    for fruit in fruits:
        if fruit in line:
            if fruit in total:
                total[fruit]+=line.count(fruit)
            else:
                total[fruit]=line.count(fruit)
f.close()
print total
```